# Updating Array in Postgres using ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I'm currently trying to update an array field in Postgres using Rails/ActiveRecord.  The following is just one of many iterations of code I've tried:

`current_acct.acct_status_will_change!
current_acct.acct_status << new_status
current_acct.save!`

I'm a bit confused by the error that I'm getting, which reads `ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (3 for 1..2)`.  The first two traces refer to ActiveUUID and the Postgres connection adapter:

`/Users/jonathanwarrick/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activeuuid-0.5.0/lib/activeuuid/patches.rb:95:in 'type_cast_with_visiting'`

`/Users/jonathanwarrick/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/cast.rb:76:in 'block in array_to_string'`

Looking at the source code found for the two errors respectively (http://ruby-doc.org/gems/docs/a/activeuuid-0.5.0/ActiveUUID/Patches/PostgreSQLQuoting.html AND http://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.1.4/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/PostgreSQLColumn/Cast.html#method-i-array_to_string), it appears that the `type_cast_with_visiting` method expects a max of two arguments, but the `array_to_string` method calls it with three.

Does anyone have any ideas of what I can do to fix this discrepancy between my two gems?  I've tried every single possible variation I can find of updating arrays in Postgres and have either run into this issue or had the save not persist, so I'm somewhat confident that it's the interplay between these two pieces causing the error rather than my approach.

Comment: The field types are designated in the Rails application when the model (and subsequent migrations) are created/run.  `acct_status` is a `string`, but there are other fields of varying types that would use a Postgres array as well, including `datetime` and `integer` fields.

Comment: Both ways work just fine in theory, but it ended up having nothing to do with my code.  I simply removed the ActiveUUID gem and everything's working with either approach.